# Deploying to IMX zkEVM Leveraging @imtbl/zkevm-contracts

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I'm building a simple NFT to deploy to IMX zkEVM... but am incurring an error during deployment.

```
error: ProviderError: unable to apply transaction even for the highest gas limit 30000000: execution reverted
      at HttpProvider.request (C:\src\gumi\contracts\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:88:21)      
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (C:\src\gumi\contracts\node_modules\@nomiclabs\hardhat-ethers\src\internal\ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

Deployment script

```
/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable dot-notation */
/* eslint-disable spaced-comment */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable camelcase */
/* eslint-disable node/no-missing-import */
/* eslint-disable no-process-exit */
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { craft__factory } from "../typechain";
import { insertRecord } from "./build_artifact";
import fs from 'fs'

dotenv.config();

// get baseURI from .env
const BASE_URI = process.env.BASE_URI!;

async function main() {
  const signers = await ethers.getSigners();

  const address = signers[0];

  const contractURI = "ipfs";
  const operatorAllowlist = address.address;
  console.log(address.address, BASE_URI, contractURI, operatorAllowlist);


  const factory = new craft__factory(address);
  const contract = await factory.deploy(address.address, BASE_URI, contractURI, operatorAllowlist);
  const nft = await contract.deployed();
    
  const data =  fs.readFileSync("artifacts/src/Gumicraft.sol/Gumicraft.json", 'utf8');
  const json = JSON.parse(data);
  const name = "Gumicraft";
  console.log(`${name} deployed to: ${nft.address}\nwith artifact ${json}`);
  await insertRecord([name, nft.address, json]);
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

NFT

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT OR Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import "./base/NFT.sol";


# contract craft is NFT {

    // a constructor that takes a baseURI, an imxContract and an array of defaultOperators
     constructor( 
        address owner_,
        string memory baseURI_,
        string memory contractURI_,
        address operatorAllowlist_
            )
        NFT(
            owner_,
            "craft",
            "GCRAFT",
            baseURI_,
            contractURI_,
            operatorAllowlist_,
            owner_,
            1000
            ) {
    }
    
}
```

the NFT Contract

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT OR Apache-2.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

import {Counters} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import {ReentrancyGuard} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

import {ImmutableERC721} from "@imtbl/zkevm-contracts/contracts/token/erc721/preset/ImmutableERC721.sol";

abstract contract NFT is ImmutableERC721, ReentrancyGuard {
    event NftMinted(address to, uint256 id, string url);

    struct Nft {
        uint256 id;
        string url;
    }

    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
    mapping(uint256 => string) private tokenParameters;

    constructor(
        address owner_,
        string memory name_,
        string memory symbol_,
        string memory baseURI_,
        string memory contractURI_,
        address operatorAllowlist_,
        address receiver_,
        uint96 feeNumerator_
    )
        ImmutableERC721(
            owner_,
            name_,
            symbol_,
            baseURI_,
            contractURI_,
            operatorAllowlist_,
            receiver_,
            feeNumerator_
        )
    {
        
    }

    function setTokenParams(uint256 tokenId, string memory tokenParams)
        public
        virtual
        onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE)
    {
        // validate that string is not empty
        require(
            bytes(tokenParams).length > 0,
            "NFT: token params can not be empty"
        );
        tokenParameters[tokenId] = tokenParams;
    }

    function getTokenFullURL(uint256 tokenId)
        public
        view
        virtual
        returns (string memory)
    {
        return
            string(
                abi.encodePacked(
                    baseURI,
                    contractURI,
                    tokenId,
                    tokenParameters[tokenId]
                )
            );
    }

    function createToken(address to, string memory tokenParams)
        public
        payable
        virtual
        nonReentrant
        onlyRole(MINTER_ROLE)
        returns (uint256)
    {
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        super._safeMint(to, newTokenId);
        setTokenParams(newTokenId, tokenParams);

        emit NftMinted(to, newTokenId, getTokenFullURL(newTokenId));
        return newTokenId;
    }

    function getTokensFor(address ownerId) public view returns (Nft[] memory) {
        uint256 balance = balanceOf(ownerId);
        require(balance > 0, "NFT: no tokens for this owner");

        uint256 total = _tokenIds.current();
        Nft[] memory tokens = new Nft[](balance);
        uint256 start = 1;
        
        for (uint256 i = 1; i < total; i++) {
            address _owner = ownerOf(i);
            if (_owner != ownerId) {
                continue;
            } else {
                tokens[start] = Nft(i, getTokenFullURL(i));
                start++;
                if (start == balance) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return tokens;
    }
}
```

I've refactored out base classes, removed logical constructor based calls and am still getting a `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit` error, which tells me there's is something potentially wrong with the SC instantiation... I'm pretty sure...

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the `hardhatg.config.ts` for the dependencyCompiler element.

```
{
    JSON...,
    dependencyCompiler: {
        paths: ["@imtbl/zkevm-contracts/contracts/allowlist/OperatorAllowlist.sol"],
},
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use the boilerplate if you're not familiar with the IMX contract inheritance.

Comment: also... the allowlist is a specific contract and must be this address


# operator allowlist contract address on ekevm testnet
OPERATOR_ALLOWLIST=0x5eBD0A78148765F294F03400e0B708e575DdcfD0